# $_POST and $this->input->post() are empty

Tags: php, forms, .htaccess, codeigniter, post

i have a problem with passing POST data. when i check the post data with firebug the data is there. but when i check it in my controller there is nothing.

this is my form:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/activiteit/saveAct" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Titel:</div>
        <input class="col-md-9" type="text" name="title" id="title"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Datum:</div>
        <input class="col-md-9" type="date" name="date" id="date"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Korte beschrijving:</div>
        <input class="col-md-9" type="text" name="short" id="short"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">Lange beschrijving:</div>
        <textarea class="col-md-9" name="long" id="long"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 spatie"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="submit" class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 btn btn-info" value="Opslaan"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

in my controller i have this:

```
public function saveAct()
{
        $this->output->enable_profiler();
        echo 'title: ' . $this->input->post('title');
}
```

[image: in this picture is the output of the saveAct controller part]
i read somewhere that this could be my htacces file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets/|assets/bootstrap/|assets/CSS/|assets/font/|assets/font-awesome/|assets/img/|assets/javascript/|assets/JQuery/|cms/|cms/bootstrap/|cms/CSS/|cms/font-awesome/|cms/img/|cms/javascript/|cms/JQuery/|public/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: can you display the result of `var_dump($_POST);` ?

Comment: what is controller name post your base url also

Comment: is it ajax request or non ajax? if ajax, show the js code also.

Comment: have u load html,url and form helper?

Comment: -DARK_DUCK: --> array(0) { }

Comment: - Rakesh Sharma: --> controller name is activiteit, function is saveAct, and they are located in Controllers/cms/...

Comment: itachi: --> non ajax request

Comment: Lokesh jain: 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('template', 'form_validation', 'database', 'datamapper');  $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like incorrect form action

Try to change :-

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>cms/activiteit/saveAct" method="post">
```

to

```
<?php echo form_open('activiteit/saveAct');?>
```

will auto get your site base url and post to controller(activiteit) method(saveAct)

For more :- https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

leave empty **Base url** in config or set it to your CI directory `http://localhost/yourdir/`

Comment: as `controller name` AND `installation directory` is not provided this answer assumes that `cms` is the `installation directory`, `activiteit` - `controller` AND `saveAct` - `method` which **CAN** be the case . **BUT** i can see `title:` echod in the OP pic, any explanation about that ?

Comment: @karan i am also assuming base url  included dir?

Comment: cms is a dir into controllers

Comment: @rakesh sharma: is i use the <?php echo form_open('cms/activiteit/saveAct');?> it works can you tell me why? it gives this as result: <form action="http://perdje.be/index.php/cms/activiteit/saveAct" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

Comment: may be missing in action url try to check what you give or echo your full action url. better if you use CI standard. also you can accept helpful answer :)